# make questions visible in edit-reviews of answers

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

When I review edits, I'll often come across an answer, where the edit is "correcting" some code posted in the answer.

Often times, it's hard to determine whether or not that "correction" is actually correct unless you have the context provided by the question.

Can we have the answers to questions be visible in the edit review queue like they are in the first posts review queue?

Comment: Do most people approve these types of edits? Unless I am an expert on the language/technology and could have answered the question myself, I'll skip them. And even if I don't skip, I'm very hesitant to approve significant changes to other people's code. The only cases where I click "Approve" are where they're fixing an obvious typo, and then I don't need to see the question.